# Azure DevOps Pipeline Not Displaying All Runs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, on-premises-instances

I'm having issues when trying to display all runs for one of my Pipelines.  I'm running on premise Azure Devops 2020 and I get a perpetual spinning Loading dialogue.  I don't have this issue in any of my other pipelines.  It seems that if I filter by run state in the problematic pipeline I am able to get past this and view some of the runs but for other states in my case "Succeeded" and "Succeeded with Issues" I continue to get the spinning loading symbol.  Any advice?

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? Please check whether my answer can help you and feel free to comment. You can focus on the suggestion 4, because many people have solved the issue through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

**Suggestion 1**

Clean the cache or load the page from a different brower and restart the Azure DevOps Server and the SQL Server machine.

**Suggestion 2**

Create a new pipeline that has the same settings as the affected pipeline.

**Suggestion 3**

You can use the REST API [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get all runs of your pipeline.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0
```

Because the cause of this question may be that the runs list is too long. You can use the REST API [Builds-Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to delete some of the runs you don't need to see whether the question can be solved.

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.0
```

**Suggestion 4**

You can refer to a [similar question](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1160833/pipeline-runs-do-not-load.html) on the Developer Community. The Jan Selbach's comment offers a solution.

> 1.Run the following SQL script to find the LeaseId of duplicate rows. Please change collection Db name according to your’s.
>
> ```
> SELECT LeaseId
> FROM [AzureDevOps_DefaultCollection].[Build].[tbl_RetentionLease] 
>  WHERE
> partitionId > 0 AND
> LeaseId NOT IN (
> SELECT MIN(LeaseId) as LeaseId
>   FROM [AzureDevOps_DefaultCollection].[Build].[tbl_RetentionLease]
>     WHERE PartitionId > 0
>     GROUP BY OwnerId,RunId
> )
> ```
>
> 2.Concatenate the LeaseIds into a comma separated list
>
> 3.Run the following PowerShell script by filling in the org, project, pat, and leaseId by passing in the comma separated list of LeaseIds
> (remember if on-prem change the https://dev.azure.com in the $uri to
> your on-prem server)

```
$org = "";
$project = "";
$pat = "";
$encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes([string]::Format("{0}:{1}", "", $pat)));
$accessToken = "Basic $encoded";
$leaseId = "";
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$project/_apis/build/retention/leases?ids=$leaseId&api-version=6.0-preview";
try {
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method DELETE -Headers @{ Authorization = $accessToken } -ContentType "application/json"
$response
}
catch {
$errorDetails = ConvertFrom-Json $_.ErrorDetails
Write-Host "StatusCode: $($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode)`nExceptionType: $($errorDetails.typeKey)`nExceptionMessage: $($errorDetails.message)"
#StackTrace: $($errorDetails.stackTrace)" 
}
```